# I cannot able to add subview to UItableviewcell

Tags: swift, uitableview

**Code**

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: 
 UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var suma=UITableViewCell()
    var sampleviewpurple=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: suma.frame.width/0, y: 0, width: suma.frame.width/2, height: suma.frame.height))
    sampleviewpurple.backgroundColor=#colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1)

    var sampleviewred=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: suma.frame.width/1, y: 0, width: suma.frame.width/2, height: suma.frame.height))
    sampleviewred.backgroundColor=#colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1)



    suma.contentView.addSubview(sampleviewpurple)
    suma.contentView.addSubview(sampleviewred)

    return suma

}




@IBOutlet weak var tab: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tab.dataSource=self
    tab.delegate=self

}

  }
```

when I try to add a subview to the suma and return to the delegate, My table view is still blank, I am returning valid data source to the data source when and also noticed the reference to the table view all is fine, But still how I can not able to add a subview to the uitableviewcell

Comment: Can you also add the code for your other UITableViewDataSource callbacks? Like numberOfRowsInSection and potentially numberOfSections? It's worth checking you're not returning 0 in either of those two callbacks. Also it's worth checking what values you have for rowHeight (can be set via a property on UITableView or from the UITableViewDelegate)

Comment: Yeah did it @KaneCheshire

Comment: Instead of  `suma.frame` use `tableview.frame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting your view's frame you are using the cell's frame which is not set yet. You should use such a view which frame is already set and on which bases you want to calculate the frame of your new views.

Try this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var sumaCell:UITableViewCell?
           sumaCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sumaCell")
    if  sumaCell == nil {
        sumaCell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "sumaCell")
    }




    var sampleviewpurple=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ((sumaCell?.frame.width)!/2), height: (sumaCell?.frame.height)!))
    sampleviewpurple.backgroundColor=#colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1)

    var sampleviewred=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: (sumaCell?.frame.width)!/2, y: 0, width: ((sumaCell?.frame.width)!/2), height: (sumaCell?.frame.height)!))
    sampleviewred.backgroundColor=#colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1)

    sumaCell?.contentView.addSubview(sampleviewpurple)
    sumaCell?.contentView.addSubview(sampleviewred)

    return sumaCell!

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is wrong with my perspective?

Comment: Yes. The reason, why your views were not visible, was the ZERO frame of your `suma` cell. All calculation was happening with zero, so the views were there but with zero size.

Comment: No needed for reuse identifier

Answer (score 1):

In the `cellForRowAt` function, you must dequeue your table cell, not instantiate UITableViewCell:

```
var suma = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the cell in code. First of all, you have to register the `UITableViewCell` in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
tab.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")
```

Then you have to use the dequeue cell in cellForRowAt method.

```
var suma = tab.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DefaultCell")
```

If you are instantiating the `cell` from `storyboard`, you just have to use dequeue cell. No need to register.

Answer (score 0):

I made three change.

1. Dequeue the cell for reusability.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   var suma = UITableViewCell()
   suma = tab.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DefaultCell")!`
   ```
2. Changed the `sampleviewpurple` and `sampleviewred` x position

   ```
   let sampleviewpurple = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: suma.frame.width/2, height: suma.frame.height))

   let sampleviewred = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: suma.frame.width/2, y: 0, width: suma.frame.width/2, height: suma.frame.height))
   ```
3. Registered the cell which is created programmatically to create a connection between `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` in `viewDidLoad` function

   ```
   tab.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")
   ```